# Django, svglib and images

Tags: python, django, pdf, svg

Im using svglib to render my svg files (rendered from a template) in django.
There seems to be a problem with how the library resolves the path of the image when rendering.
I was wondering if anyone has implemented this or knows a better way to convert svg (that includes images) to PDF?

EDIT:
My view:

```
def certificate_image(response, id, output):
    ...
    ...
    data = certificate_template.render(c)

    if output == 'pdf':   
        doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data)
        svg = doc.documentElement

        svgRenderer = SvgRenderer()
        svgRenderer.render(svg)
        drawing = svgRenderer.finish()
        buffer = StringIO()
        renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, buffer)
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=certificate.pdf'
        pdf = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
        response.write(pdf)

    return response
```

Comment: Can you show what you've done up to now (code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about SVG to HTML? It depends what SVG you are converting but sometimes the results are identical.
Let me know if this is relevant and helps or if you have any query.

Go the instruction page where the tool is also located.

http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/svgsource.php

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used svglib, but there are many excellent command-line tools that can render SVG to PDF. Inkscape has a complete command-line interface, and can be run headless. Just look at the man page for more information on this. Another good one is the [Batik SVG Rasterizer](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html), which uses Java, but can be run from the command line. Finally, ImageMagick (the "convert" utility on the command line) has some support for SVG conversion to other raster and vector formats.

You can probably see where this is going. You can use python's os.system function to perform a system call to one of these command-line tools, dump the results into a file, or, for tools that support it, to stdout, and then read the results into a buffer. Use the buffer exactly as you are doing now.